# SVN: Synchronize branch with trunk in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, svn, merge, subversive, synchronize

I have an SVN branch and a trunk. The trunk changes regularly and the branch doesn't.

Every now and then (let's say once per week) I want to update the local working copy of the branch with the latest changes of the trunk.

Ideally I would want to do this the same way as I do it with the latest version of the branch: with Eclipse : Team->Synchronize, so I can review all changes before updating.

Is this also possible with a *different* repository (for example : trunk) ?
If not, how do people review the changes before updating then??

I looked at Team->Merge, but this seems to update the changes directly to my working copy, without the possibility to review the changes first (the Preview-function is confusing, I think, and doesn't provide the nice side-by-side view of changes/conflicts that Synchronize has).

Answer (score 6):

The right way to do this is with Merge.  Subclipse includes a merge client that makes this easy to do.  You are right that it does not give you a true preview, but the way it works is better from a Subversion perspective.  The Merge Results view UI is basically the same as the Synchronize view.  It lets you easily examine every change that the merge made in your working copy and the Eclipse compare editor that it opens makes it very easy to take out any parts of the change that you do not want in your code before you commit.

The problem with trying to do this from the Synchronize view is that you are then doing the merge yourself using code editors and Subversion has no awareness of what is merged.  If you let Subversion first do the merge, then it can update all of its metadata properly and it is perfectly fine for you to then fixup the code to be the way you want it before you commit the results of the merge.

Comment: very strange decision to do the merge first and then afterwards review the changes... can't believe that anyone would prefer this instead of reviewing the changes first, before ruining your working copy... I want to see what other people have done, BEFORE I even want anything to do with it... now I have to cleanup other people's mess when trying to see what possible updates/bigfixes are available...

Comment: In what way do you feel it ruins your working copy?  You should not generally merge into a working copy that has uncommitted modifications.  If you do not like the result of the merge, there is an Undo option that puts your working copy back the way it was.  Individual changes can easily be removed using the Revert option.  I find it very strange that someone would want to review every change rather than letting the tool do the work for them and then review what it did.

Comment: Maybe I just need to get used to it. I just think it's odd to actually merge to the working copy and only then see what other people have changed. I just want an easy way to see all upcoming changes and THEN decide if I need to merge...

Comment: The merge dialog in Eclipse has a `Unified Diff` button which creates a diff file of all the changes that would be made.  While it doesn't include issue numbers with each diff it is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I'd checkout both branch and trunk as a separate eclipse projects into workspace. Then use some merging tool, for example [meld](http://meld.sourceforge.net/) to merge changes between them. After merge you can refresh branch in Eclipse and synchronize it with svn repository - now you can review all changes. (it's how I do it, since I do not believe svn eclipse plugin ;))

Comment: I didn't like svn in Eclipse too, but Subversive is quite nice now. Even with a big project with thousands of files it's usable (not fast though, an update sometimes takes a couple of minutes)

Answer (score 0):

I agree that it is not really intuitive by design, but Mark is right, you "synchronize" your changes when committing them back to the trunk:

- first make sure your local branch is completely synchronized with your repository branch (no changes)
- *Team* -> *Merge...* your local copy of the branch with the repository trunk
- you now have a local version of that merge
- you can locally edit this version, make sure tests are working and there are no compiler errors
- finally you synchronize your local merged branch version with the repository branch and commit all changes that have been made

besides, the same way you'll merge your branch back into the repository trunk

- make sure all changes of your branch are committed to the repository branch
- switch to the trunk *Team* -> *Switch...*
- merge your trunk with your branch *Team* -> *Merge...* (Tab 'Reintegrate')
- you now have a local version of the merge, you may edit the changes and review them, make sure that you have a working version now
- synchronize your local trunk (merged version) with the repository trunk
- commit all changes that you want to appear in the trunk

i recommend to commit all changes that you've made locally to your merge, since you've tested them locally. if you commit just a few changes, make sure the repository version is still working then with missing changes